# Mailgun email validator

Tags: javascript, email-validation, mailgun

i got the plugin and its working as expected ,except now all i want is to disable the submit button if the email was invalid & re-enable it again if the email became valid ,so how to do that ?

**JS**

```
$('#email').mailgun_validator({
    api_key: 'xxxx',
    in_progress: validation_in_progress,
    success: validation_success,
    error: validation_error,
});

// in_progress
function validation_in_progress() {
    $('#status').html("<img src='assets/loading.gif' height='16'/>");
}

// success
function validation_success(data) {
    $('#status').html(get_suggestion_str(data['is_valid'], data['did_you_mean']));
}

// invalid
function validation_error(error_message) {
    $('#status').html(error_message);
}

// suggest a valid email
function get_suggestion_str(is_valid, alternate) {
    if (alternate) {
        return '<small class="help-block warning">Did you mean <b>' + alternate + '</b>?</small>';
    } else if (is_valid) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return '<small class="help-block error">Address is invalid.</small>';
    }
}
```

and the code for the submit btn

```
$("#validate_submit").attr('disabled');
```

but i don't know where i should add it to the js above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got it working.

```
function validation_success(data) {
    $('#status').html(get_suggestion_str(data['is_valid'], data['did_you_mean']));
    if (!data['is_valid'] || data['did_you_mean']) {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
        console.log('else');
    }
}
```